# Contextual menu and selected item

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, office-ui-fabric

I am referring to Multiselect ContextualMenu from https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/ContextualMenu/ContextualMenu.html and I was able to write a sample. In the HTML, I added another button(Apply) on click of which I want to extract the selected items in the ContextualMenu.

Can anybody help me with the javascript code which will give me the selected items from the contextual menu on click of a button(Apply)?

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It is not related to fabricjs tag.

Comment: onApply(), I tried document.querySelectorAll(".ms-ContextualMenu-link") and it does not return anything. I looked into the HTML of the document and I see the entire <ul> node missing from the html. Any idea why? Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible in your case, but it will be a good suggestion to use ReactJs together with Fabric Ui. At least you will not have that kind of issues. 
I used contextualmenu component and it was easy to implement.